# ATI Radeon Display Driver

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, updates

I have a dell laptop running vista.  i recently tried to upgrade the display driver downloaded from dell and installed via ATI catalyst.  After the installation and reboot I receive the message:

Could not load file or assembly 'CCC.Implementation, Version=2.0.2660.39033,culture=neutral, public key token=90ba9c70f846762e' or one of its dependencies.  the system can not find the file specified.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it could be an issue with your .NET framework as the Catalyst Control Center relies on it heavily.  Try downloading and reinstalling the .NET framework, version 2.0, from Microsoft's website **[here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en)** and then restart your computer.  (I had a similar problem with my own ATI card).

An alternative could be to uninstall the ATI Catalyst suite and download/install JUST the driver, unless you require all of the features of the Catalyst Control Center.  There is an option for this on ATI's website.

Comment: error message - .net already installed exiting program

Comment: My experience was it should repair what's already there - can you remove from add/remove programs, restart, and then reattempt installation?  You may need to show all updates and remove any 2.0 updates in the list prior to the 2.0 .net framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the graphics card driver and the ATI Catalyst suite, then download and install the **latest** Catalyst driver suite from **[AMD/ATI](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)**, not from Dell.

Comment: my system has an ati x1270  couldn't find a match.  closest to choose from was an x1300